# limit size of the string in glob argument?

Tags: perl, glob

I am using the `glob` function in order to factorize some lists.

Everything was working fine until now, It seems that the `glob` function doesn't work if the string exeeds a certain length.

In my code I have something like

```
my @output = glob("{a,b,c}__{d,e,f}__{g,h,i}");
```

and got the output

```
"a__d__g","a__d__h",...,"c__f__i"
```

the problem occurs when the string is too long, it seems it starts when the string is longer than 254 characters (254 not included) long (without the `{` and `}`)
When the string is too long the glob function doesn't make the concatenation on each `{}` ,it ends before the "group" that make the string exeed 254 chars

Is it a known limitation of glob? Is there something to do about it?

I belive this is a limitation since 255 = b11111111 (maybe some sort of overflow)

What do you think about it?

thanks :)

Comment: The glob function is intended for generating a list of filenames. Have you considered generating your strings differently, e.g. through a recursive function `cross_product(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'])`?

Comment: @amon I tried with the algorithm::NestedLoops module, it worked fine on my 64bit version of perl but I had to switch to 32bit and I was unable to find it on 32bit ppm

Comment: @toolic I really can't,  have literally thousand of strings, some are above the 254 char so it works but when I keep the same format and a size above 254 char it doesn't work anymore

Comment: So install it from CPAN like the rest of the world: `cpan Algorithm::Loops`

Comment: Algorithm::Loops is a pure-Perl module. It is in no way architecture-dependent, so 64-bit vs 32-bit is irrelevant. You could even just copy the relevant code from the module (the module's license allows this). Or just write your own function. Or most sensibly, install from CPAN directly instead of restricting yourself to PPM. You have many options.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution:

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $iter = NestedLoops([
   [qw( a b c )],
   [qw( d e f )],
   [qw( g h i )],
]);

while (my @vals = $iter->()) {
   my $s = join("__", @vals);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, tried with that module, it worked on a 64bits version of Perl, but I had to switch to 32bit to ensure compability on all devices the code is intended for. I am unable to find it on 32 bit ppm, if I get I from CPAN it works but i'm not sure it is 100% compatible with 32bit perl since it is not on activeState's repository